# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined

Tags: web3js, javascript, contract-debugging, error, frontend

I'm getting this error. Can someone please help me

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined
at add_details ((index):140)

line:140--> var myContract = new Web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractaddress, {from: account, gasPrice: '5000000', gas: '500000'});

at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):31)

I'm using remix, metamask and testing it with ganache. The smart contract is deployed on remix.

https://github.com/shrutimishra1214/error/blob/main/index.html

Comment: Well, you are missing "0x" at your contract address at line 137.

Comment: Smart contracts addresses always start with '0x'. Check line 137 in your code.

Comment: Also it is not advisable to declare your abi as a variable. Save it as a separate file and then import it into your script, same applies to your javascript code.

Comment: I added 0 at line 137. The error is still the same. Thanks anyways

Comment: It appears you are using an old web3 version 1.2.8 the latest is 1.3.4. Other error is you should use`var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(.....)`, using lowercase `web3`, also check if `account` is initialized properly.